# JSON file and dictionary item into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have `dictionary` and `JSON` files that I want to combine into a dataframe.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
jsonn = """
        {
            "Cake_make": {
            "id": "25803",
            "dday": "2009-01-01T15:00:00",
            "cake_name": "chocolate",
            "Mainmetrics": "7.6",
            "TC": "10000.02",
            "LSS":"102341.32",
            "LTC":"12321.65"
            
        },
        "Jd": "2009-01-01T15:00:00" 
       }
        """

my_dic = {'Cake_make': {'id': 'matched', 'dday': 'matched', 'cake_name': 'Not Matched'}}
json_data = json.loads(jsonn)
```

I've found some examples regarding writing JSON files into CSV and merging JSON files but not the exact solution that I'm looking for.

Expected output
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the fields manually:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

jsonn = """
        {
            "Cake_make": {
            "id": "25803",
            "dday": "2009-01-01T15:00:00",
            "cake_name": "chocolate",
            "Mainmetrics": "7.6",
            "TC": "10000.02",
            "LSS":"102341.32",
            "LTC":"12321.65"
            
        },
        "Jd": "2009-01-01T15:00:00" 
       }
        """
my_dic = {'Cake_make': {'id': 'matched', 'dday': 'matched', 'cake_name': 'Not Matched'}}
json_data = json.loads(jsonn)

combined_dict = {
    "id": json_data["Cake_make"]["id"],
    "dday": json_data["Cake_make"]["dday"],
    "Jd": json_data["Jd"],
    "cake_name": json_data["Cake_make"]["cake_name"],
    "dict": my_dict
}

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=combined_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way we can write a loop to get those column names in nested if else ?

Comment: sorry not sure I understand exactly what you mean?

Comment: instead of manually typing, getting those column names in a programmatic way.

Comment: of course it can be done programatically, however it is unclear which fields you are trying to add at which location. My answer is modelled off your screenshot of expected output. If you could provide a larger dataset, along with expected output, I can help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: In the expected output its shown that `id`, `dday`, `jd`, `cake_name` and `dict` columns requested but I would like to define those column names programatically.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan's answer shows, it is probably easiest to build the exact dictionary you want (`combined_dict`) beforehand and simply pass that to `DataFrame`, rather than trying to re-arrange the data after getting it into the df. You do not post the code you found on the internet that didn't do what you wanted, so I'm not sure what you were trying that didn't work.

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-loads-in-python/) what json.loads actually does. It converts the JSON string into a dictionary you can traverse via keys. Read up about traversing python dictionary structures, there are many intuitive methods to make it easy (enumerating elements, looping through them, etc).

Edit: To attempt to answer your further comment, there are methods such as [dict.keys()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-dictionary-keys-as-a-list/) to dynamically read the keys (which you seem to be using as column names) from a dictionary object, and other helpful methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's always `pd.json_normalize`...

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)
df['dict'] = [my_dic]
print(df)

# Output:
                    Jd Cake_make.id       Cake_make.dday Cake_make.cake_name Cake_make.Mainmetrics Cake_make.TC Cake_make.LSS Cake_make.LTC                                                                             dict
0  2009-01-01T15:00:00        25803  2009-01-01T15:00:00           chocolate                   7.6     10000.02     102341.32      12321.65  {'Cake_make': {'id': 'matched', 'dday': 'matched', 'cake_name': 'Not Matched'}}
```